# Can Oracle Enterprise Manager Grid Control 11g can manage databases that support oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

The reason is that I have Oracle Database 10g installed and I am unable to download patches of Oracle Enterprise Manager Grid control 10g from oracle.com. However they are recommending a higher version of 11g . Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with 11g grid control you can manage 10gR2 databases, and vice-versa as far as I recall.

As to the particular versions, there is a compatibility matrix in Oracle Support, I don't believe it is public document, however.